# How to reroute on same component with dynamic id angular 8

Tags: angular

how can we re-route on same component when dynamic id changes on component.

This is my route:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: `${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("id"))}`,
    pathMatch: "full",
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: ":id",
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    data: { title: "Dashboard" }
    
  }    
];
```

I want to reload dashboard component whenever dynamic id changes.

How can we achieve this ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

From inside of DashboardComponent:

```
this.router.navigate(['/', { id: newId }]);
```

or

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(`/${newId}`);
```

PS: suggest you to change your Routes like

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ":id",
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    data: { title: "Dashboard" }
  },
  { 
    path: '',   
    redirectTo: '/', // redirect to `main page`
    pathMatch: 'full' 
  },
  { 
    path: '**', // Wildcard route for a 404 page
    component: PageNotFoundComponent 
  },
];
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey, but above solution doesnt work for me.